# Entry::Occupied.get() returns a value referencing data owned by the current function even though hashmap should have the ownership

Tags: rust, ownership

My goal was to implement the suggested improvement on the *cacher struct* of the rust book chapter 13.1, that is creating a struct which takes a function and uses memoization to reduce the number of calls of the given function. To do this, I created a struct with an *HashMap*

```
struct Cacher<T, U, V>
where T: Fn(&U) -> V, U: Eq + Hash
{
  calculation: T,
  map: HashMap<U,V>,
}
```

and two methods, one constructor and one which is resposible of the memoization.

```
impl<T, U, V> Cacher<T, U, V>
    where T: Fn(&U) -> V, U: Eq + Hash
{
    fn new(calculation: T) -> Cacher<T,U,V> {
        Cacher {
            calculation,
            map: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    fn value(&mut self, arg: U) -> &V {
        match self.map.entry(arg){
            Entry::Occupied(occEntry) => occEntry.get(),
            Entry::Vacant(vacEntry) => {
                let argRef = vacEntry.key();
                let result = (self.calculation)(argRef);
                vacEntry.insert(result)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used the *Entry* enum, because I didn't found a better way of deciding if the *HashMap* contains a key and - if it doesn't - calculating the value and inserting it into the HashMap as well as returning a reference to it.

If I want to compile the code above, I get an error which says that *occEntry* is borrowed by it's *.get()* method (which is fine by me) and that *.get()* **"returns a value referencing data owned by the current function"**.

My understanding is that the compiler thinks that the value which *occEntry.get()* is referencing to is owned by the function *value(...)*. But shouldn't I get a reference of the value of type V, which is owned by the *HashMap*? Is the compiler getting confused because the value is owned by the function and saved as *result* for a short moment?

```
let result = (self.calculation)(argRef);
vacEntry.insert(result)
```

Please note that it is necessary to save the result temporarily because the *insert* method consumes the key and such *argRef* is not valid anymore. Also I acknowledge that the signature of *value* can be problematic (see [Mutable borrow from HashMap and lifetime elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56181266/mutable-borrow-from-hashmap-and-lifetime-elision)) but I tried to avoid a *Copy* Trait Bound.

For quick reproduction of the problem I append the *use statements* necessary. Thanks for your help.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::cmp::Eq;
use std::hash::Hash;
use std::collections::hash_map::{OccupiedEntry, VacantEntry, Entry};
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's take a look at [`OccupiedEntry::get()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/struct.OccupiedEntry.html#method.get)'s signature:

```
 pub fn get(&self) -> &V
```

What this signature is telling us is that the reference obtained from the `OccupiedEntry` can only live as long as the `OccupiedEntry` itself. However, the `OccupiedEntry` is a local variable, thus it's dropped when the function returns.

What we want is a reference whose lifetime is bound to the `HashMap`'s lifetime. Both [`Entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html) and [`OccupiedEntry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/struct.OccupiedEntry.html) have a lifetime parameter (`'a`), which is linked to the `&mut self` parameter in [`HashMap::entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry). We need a method on `OccupiedEntry` that returns a `&'a V`. There's no such method, but there's one that returns a `'&a mut V`: [`into_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/struct.OccupiedEntry.html#method.into_mut). A mutable reference can be implicitly coerced to a shared reference, so all we need to do to make your method compile is to replace `get()` with `into_mut()`.

```
fn value(&mut self, arg: U) -> &V {
    match self.map.entry(arg) {
        Entry::Occupied(occ_entry) => occ_entry.into_mut(),
        Entry::Vacant(vac_entry) => {
            let arg_ref = vac_entry.key();
            let result = (self.calculation)(arg_ref);
            vac_entry.insert(result)
        }
    }
}
```