# quick_xml Attributes to HashMap

Tags: xml, rust

I want to convert a [quick_xml](https://docs.rs/quick-xml/0.18.1/quick_xml/) [Attributes](https://docs.rs/quick-xml/0.18.1/quick_xml/events/attributes/struct.Attributes.html) variable to a `HashMap<&str, &str>`. But I am getting an error like below.

**Error**

```
    |
171 | / ...                   (str::from_utf8(attr.key).unwrap(), unsafe {
172 | | ...                       std::str::from_utf8_unchecked(attr.value.as_ref())
    | |                                                         ---------- `attr.value` is borrowed here
173 | m| ...                   })
    | |________________________^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

I have googled and copied some codes from [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-map-cow-a-u8-to-a-str/37103) to convert `Cow<[u8]>` to a `&str`.

**Code**

```rust
let attrs: HashMap<&str, &str> = e
         .attributes() // quick_xml::events::attributes::Attributes
         .map(|a| {
               let attr = a.unwrap();

               (str::from_utf8(attr.key).unwrap(), unsafe {
                      std::str::from_utf8_unchecked(attr.value.as_ref())
               })
         })
         .collect();
```

[Full Code](https://github.com/whizsid/osm-to-sql/blob/7b7bf5c7611e1e3500a6ec5817d9423499a57f7c/src/main.rs#L166)

Comment: You need an owned version of `&str` aka String. change attrs to HashMap<String,String>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entry::Occupied.get() returns a value referencing data owned by the current function even though hashmap should have the ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60129097/entryoccupied-get-returns-a-value-referencing-data-owned-by-the-current-func)